# How does 濃's semantic component, 氵, appertain to 'thick, strong, concentrated'?

Tags: etymology

> 略說: 從「[水](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B0%B4)」，「[農](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%BE%B2)」聲。本指露水多，引伸為厚、密的意思。

1. I read [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%BF%83), but I can't see how (pure) water itself can be construed "thick, strong, concentrated"!  I've never heard of water being described as "thick, strong, concentrated", which usually describes beverages brewed with ingredients OTHER THAN water! This meaning figures in [濃厚](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BF%83%E5%8E%9A#Chinese).
2. I also can't picture how dew can be construed as "thick, strong, concentrated". Why? First, the primary sense of 氵 is water, not dew. Second, dew isn't a common concept in daily life, compared to water as a life necessity. Humans all need water to survive, but we don't need dew. Third,  dew exists as beads or globules, which don't feel "thick, strong, concentrated" to me. It's not as if ONE dew blob can fill a swimming pool!

[image]

Comment: Dew's definition is "tiny drops of WATER that form on cool surfaces at night, when atmospheric vapour condenses." And characters with 氵can be related to other fluids, like juice 汁 or soup 汤, not just water. What's wrong if it's a beverage? Doesn't the beverage have water in it? I don't really get this point of this question, sorry

Comment: `I also can't picture how dew can be construed as "thick, strong, concentrated". Why? First, the primary sense of 氵 is water, not dew.` You can’t see how dew can be construed as "thick, strong, concentrated", because you decided to interpret the character based on water, and not dew? Are you sure you’re asking the right questions? Are you sure you even know what exactly you’re trying to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dew is an integral part of life. People concerned with agriculture or agronomy spend a good amount of time studying/forecasting dew amounts, even today. Classic texts in many languages also feature a strong emphasis on dew metaphorically, if not literally.

The difference between light dew and heavy dew, i.e.: little vs. a lot, can be of great importance in an agricultural society. (It also seems to indicate daily wind speeds as well.)

The extended meanings from "heavy dew" to dense/concentrated are logical, as the water droplets would be plentifully placed with little space in between them.

Answer (score 0):

濃 can be used for any types of fluid - "血濃於水", "一碗濃湯", "一口濃痰".

Also, it can be used for describing the smell of dietary/beverages - "哈蜜瓜有很濃重的香味", "這杯咖啡味道很濃(厚)".

In addition, it can be used to indicate the thickness and depth of feeling towards a person or things. - "她對他有着濃厚的感情", "他對這件事有着濃厚的興趣".

Finally, 濃 is used for mixtures with a high concentration of certain substance - "濃霧", "濃煙", "濃度", "濃縮".

Note that all of the above uses infer to the physical condition of the **blood - a thick, sticky, water-like fluid**. Also, in earlier (ancient) use, it was mainly associated with the smells or looks of the **agriculture products (農產品) and water mixtures.**